# Form data not being entered into the SQL statement

Tags: forms

I have created a form which is not entering the data I enter in the fields into the sql statement. I just got the error:

> user warning: Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY' query: INSERT INTO subscription_info (first, last, email, phone) VALUES ('','','','') in C:\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\modules\drupal620x120318224310\sites\all\modules\email_form\email_form.module on line 124.

Here is the code:

```
function email_form_my_form($form_state) {
  $form['info'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Personal Information'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => FALSE,
  );

  $form['info']['first'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('First name'),
    //'#default_value' => $form_state['values']['first'], // changed
    '#description' => "Please enter your first name.",
    '#size' => 20,
    '#maxlength' => 20,
   );

   $form['info']['last'] = array(
     '#type' => 'textfield',
     '#title' => t('Last name'),
     '#size' => 20,
     '#maxlength' => 20
     //'#default_value' => $form_state['values']['last'], // added
   );

   $form['info']['email'] = array(
     '#type' => 'textfield',
     '#title' => t('Email address'),
     '#size' => 30
   );

  $form['info']['phone'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Phone Number'),
    '#description' => "Format: 555-555-5555",
    '#size' => 10,
    '#maxsize' => 10
  );

  $form['subscription'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Subscription Information'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => FALSE
  );

  $form['subscription']['content'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#title' => t('Events'),
    '#description' => t('Please chose which events you would like to follow'),
    '#options' => array(
      'Baseball' => t('Baseball'),
      'Basketball' => t('Basketball'),
    ),
  );                    

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
  );

  $form['clear'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Reset form',
    '#validate' => array('email_form_my_form_clear'),
  );

  return $form;
}

function email_form_my_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  //unset($form_state['storage']);
if (db_query("INSERT INTO {subscription_info} (first, last, email, phone) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s')", $form_state['values']['info']['first'], $form_state['values']['info']['last'], $form_state['values']['info']['email'], $form_state['values']['info']['phone'])) {
      //$form_state['values']['subscription']['content'] use this later...
      drupal_set_message(t('The form has been submitted.'));
}
else {
      drupal_set_message(t('The form had an error in it.'));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Drupal flattens the form values array so the element set at `$form['info']['first']` will be available in `$form_state['values']['first']`.

If you want it to be available in `$form_state['values']['info']['first']` you need to set the [`#tree`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6#tree) attribute on the parent element:

```
$form['info'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => t('Personal Information'),
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  '#collapsed' => FALSE,
  '#tree' => TRUE
);
```

There's more info available on the [`#tree and #parents`](http://drupal.org/node/48643) documentation page if you're interested.

The alternative is to change your `db_query()` call to use the "default" method:

```
db_query("INSERT INTO {subscription_info} (first, last, email, phone) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s')", 
  $form_state['values']['first'], 
  $form_state['values']['last'],  
  $form_state['values']['email'],
  $form_state['values']['phone']
);
```

Comment: I never knew about this, thanks. But, I did the alternative change and took out all of ['info']'s and I got the same error, its not doing the insert. I even used devel to re-install the module, though that shouldn't have made a difference... Any other ideas?

Comment: Is it the same error message ? If yes, then you have to check your values before inserting them, to make sure they won't try to create a new record similar to one which already exists in the table.

Comment: @countzero is right, according to the error you're inserting a new record with the same primary key (email address) as one that exists in the table. Since primary keys must be unique this is causing the error. You might want to have a look at the [`db_merge()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_merge/7) function which helps out with UPSERT statements

Comment: Yes, its the same error. This is exactly what happens. I start from scratch (by uninstalling the module via devel), fill in the form and it says it submits fine. I look in the database and see nothing. I then fill in the form again with new information and get the above error message... @countzero, What do you mean by check values? Do you mean validation?

Comment: @clive, I don't know what I can possibly be doing wrong, by I will check up db_merger() later on today. See my comments to countzero

Comment: You don't insert in the database you believe you do. On the first submission, a record is inserted, then, on the second submission, another try is made, which fails because the primary key of the table disallows it. It's absolutely sure. Check your second database and you'll see.

Comment: @countzero, I looked at the database in phpadmin. I see one record with blank values for each of my for columns. That is why I am getting the primary key error. But why is my form info not entered into the database?

Comment: I got it! For some reason, it only works when I made the parent a tree. When I tried the second way (by taking out ['info']) it didn't work.

Comment: @user1015214 Glad you got it sorted :)